# Unable to sink record to KafkaSink in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a data like {name: "abc", age: 20} being read from kafka in a flink code using Java.

I am trying to sink this data into Kafka from flink

```
KafkaSink<AllIncidentsDataPOJO> sink = KafkaSink.<AllIncidentsDataPOJO>builder()
                        .setBootstrapServers(this.bootstrapServer)
                        .setKafkaProducerConfig(kafkaProps)
                        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                                        .setTopic("flink-all-incidents")
                                        .setValueSerializationSchema(new IncidentsSerializationSchema()).build())
                        .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
                        .build();
```

**IncidentSerializationSchema**

```
public class IncidentsSerializationSchema implements SerializationSchema<AllIncidentsDataPOJO> {
    static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(AllIncidentsDataPOJO element) {
        if (objectMapper == null) {
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }
        try {
//            System.out.println("Returned value: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(element).getBytes());
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(element).getBytes();
        } catch (
                org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

Now when I print within the above class it gives me a serialized message of say

```
Returned value: [B@6f29a884
Returned value: [B@743145c5
Returned value: [B@6aa6b431
Returned value: [B@208c0151
Returned value: [B@1a3a0c6d
Returned value: [B@7972da35
Returned value: [B@1097059f
Returned value: [B@6013a87b
Returned value: [B@27b252dc
Returned value: [B@288478b7
Returned value: [B@54185041
Returned value: [B@970646b
```

But when I try to use data.sinkTo(sink) after initializing KafkaSink, it starts disconnecting

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Node 8 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 35 due to node 8 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 292ms, elapsed time since send: 292ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Node 8 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 37 due to node 8 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 639ms, elapsed time since send: 639ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Node 8 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-sink-0-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-sink-0-1, transactionalId=kafka-sink-0-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 38 due to node 8 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 875ms, elapsed time since send: 875ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
```

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: You may want to confirm that your Kafka configuration (e.g. bootstrap server) is properly configured and pointing to the correct location and verify that if you are using any type of authentication (i.e. SASL, etc.) that those properties are properly configured as well.

It might not hurt to share _roughly_ what those configurations look like to rule out a configuration problem.

Comment: But when I run this code, if the mentioned topic is not present, it creates this topic on the server. This implies that the connection is a success. But when it comes to writing the data to the topic, that is where it starts failing.